# how to find a route to travel between two cities, using an accumulator in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate `directTrain/2` which defines a direct path from place `A` to `B`.
Given a knowledge base, I want to define a predicate `route(A,B,Route)` that will give the outcome as a form of a list containing the route from `A` to `B`.

I understand that this is the same as figuring out if person `A` is a descend of person `B`, so I know that the Yes/No version of this should be something like this:

```
route(A,B) :-
   directTrain(A,B).
route(A,B) :-
   directTrain(A,C),
   route(C,B).
```

What I am lacking is the understanding of how to do this with an arity of 3, when the third variable will accumulate the final route.
I want to reach the following outcome:

Given the following knowledge base ...

```
directTrain(ny,la).
directTrain(la,paris).
directTrain(paris,rome).
```

... the answer to the query ...

```
route(ny,rome,R).
```

... should be:

```
R = [ny,la,paris,rome]
```

I am very new to Prolog so I hope I will learn a lot from the answers. Thanks!

Comment: Find the "search box" on this stackoverflow.com page, and look for "[prolog] travel route". You'll get lots of hits.

Comment: @lurker I tried that, and I found allot of answers to the Yes/No version of this question, but none of them helped me with finding the route itself, and not if there is a route.

Comment: I'm a little surprised since this question has come up many times, including the display of the route itself. The yes/no is the answer to "if there is a route".

Comment: I just tried the search and [the very first post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386947/route-planning-in-prolog) has code that gives a route.